# Vue multi modal and component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a problem, in the code below, I will generate the button with the data actions, and each button to display different modal according to the modalTemplate property inside when clicking, and replace the template content through the slot.

```
<div class="button" v-for="item in actions">
  <modal v-if="item.show" @close="item.show = false" @click="item.show = true">{{item.modalTemplate}}</modal>
  /div>
```

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: function() {
    return {
      actions: [{
        name: 'add-new-1',
        show: false,
        modalTemplate: `<div slot="title"@click="$emit('close')>add new 1</div>`
      }, {
        name: 'add-new-2',
        show: false,
        modalTemplate: `<div slot="body" @click="$emit('close')>this is a body</div>`
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: what's the question or the specific problem?

Comment: @boussadjrabrahim hi~ the code demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/lyplba/eywraw8t/422880/

Comment: please check this https://jsfiddle.net/d4gq95nr/

Comment: @boussadjrabrahim :D, ye~ i used before... but it can't bind event like $emit, it just a string

Answer (score 0):

`{{item.modalTemplate}}` won't compile a string into a vue component.

Place the `<div slot="title"@click="$emit('close')>add new 1</div>` in the `<template>` inside the `<modal>` and use `v-if` to change what to show, for example:

in <template>:

```
<div v-if="item.title" slot="title" @click="$emit('close')>{{item.title}}</div>
```

in <script>:

```
data: () => ({
  actions: [{
    name: 'add-new-1',
    show: false,
    title: "add new 1"
  },
  ...
```

Comment: ye, this way is work for me and i used before~ but I want that it can more dynamic, because the modal maybe replace by any content... here is code demo: https://jsfiddle.net/lyplba/eywraw8t/422880/, or I just can use Vue.componet?